# Is there any loop way that will help not to repeat same code again?

Tags: jquery

I am doing custom collapse using jquery, but my way of writing is to repeat code. Is there any  way not to repeat code? Plz help...

```
$('#muqfeas878zalh4vxayb1rkqyfjctk1v .block-title').wrap("<div class='click-wrapper-one'></div>");
$('#muqfeas878zalh4vxayb1rkqyfjctk1v .block-title').after("<div class='drop-arrow-down'></div>");
$('#muqfeas878zalh4vxayb1rkqyfjctk1v .block-title').addClass("drop-arrow-down-title");
$('#muqfeas878zalh4vxayb1rkqyfjctk1v .click-wrapper-one').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("collapsed");
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active drop-arrow-down");
  $(".field-hanger").toggle();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

again I have to write same code for next block by changing some class. And there are so many blocks like this.

```
$('#gwe1osm3ylp7imv4bbu1fquivij15wk6 .block-title').wrap("<div class='click-wrapper-two'></div>");
$('#gwe1osm3ylp7imv4bbu1fquivij15wk6 .block-title').after("<div class='drop-arrow-down'></div>");
$('#gwe1osm3ylp7imv4bbu1fquivij15wk6 .block-title').addClass("drop-arrow-down-title");
$('#gwe1osm3ylp7imv4bbu1fquivij15wk6 .click-wrapper-two').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("collapsed"); 
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active drop-arrow-down");
  $(".field-door-type").toggle();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I would wrap the code in a function that accepts the ID and the index:

```
function prepBlockTitles(id, togglerClass, index) {
    var blockTitles = $(id + ' .block-title');

    blockTitles.wrap("<div class='click-wrapper-"+index+"'></div>");
    blockTitles.after("<div class='drop-arrow-down'></div>");
    blockTitles.addClass("drop-arrow-down-title");
    $(id + ' .click-wrapper-'+index).on('click', function(e) {
      $(this).toggleClass("collapsed");
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("active drop-arrow-down");
      $(togglerClass).toggle();
      e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Then you can put all your IDs in an array and loop over it and pass the id and index to the function.

Comment: Abstraction is our friend =]

Comment: @AlexanderNied this is the correct answer and you beat me to the punch.  I was just about to post something similar.  However, the only addition is I would also name the function as well.

Comment: @Andreas - _excellent_ point-- no I was just answering quickly during work bc I saw this.  I'll update, thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderNied what about the .field-hanger class?, That class also different for every block.

Comment: @MukundaBhatta -- my apologies, I missed that-- you could make an array that stores an object with the id and the toggled class, like: `[{id: "#muqfeas878zalh4vxayb1rkqyfjctk1v", toggleClass: ".field-hanger"}, {id: "#gwe1osm3ylp7imv4bbu1fquivij15wk6", toggleClass: ".field-door-type"}]`.  Then you could iterate over this and pass both into the function, which would then be updated with a `toggleClass` argument.

Comment: @Andreas -- yep, sorry, my jQuery is rusty.  Got it now.

Comment: @Andreas -- I feel like I should figure out a way to funnel you some of the vote points I got on this... :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice on tuning this-- I *think* the various issues raised have all been addressed now in the answer as posted above.